# Delphi: Doesn't load a DLL unless I install Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I have a DLL that gets loaded in my application, like so:

```
procedure LoadTessDLL;
var
  DLLHandle: THandle;
begin
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(ExtractFilePath(application.exename) + 'tessdll.dll'));
  if DLLHandle >= 32 then
  begin
    TessDLLLoaded := True;
```

We discovered that on an XP PC with Service Pack 2, the DLL fails to get loaded (the DLLHAndle = 0 etc), UNLESS we install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable. Then it gets loaded and works just fine.

Please can you help me get this working without it?

Comment: Richard, testing the return of [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175.aspx) against '32' was correct long, long ago (16bit API). Test against '0' (NULL).

Comment: To clarify... 0 means it's not loaded, > 0 means it was loaded?

Comment: Just built your tesseract-ocr binary **statically linking** all of RTL

Comment: @user205376 Haha, a lot easier said than done. I'm a Delphi Developer, and although I have access to the sourcecode, I wouldn't know how to do what you've just said - i just get the DLL file, and I also see I get a .lib file which up until now I haven't included. Gonna try and test it with the .lib file in the same folder now, and see what happens. Probably a long shot...

Comment: I said a typo, actually. Of course, i meant **build**, not *built*.

Comment: @Richard, as you can see for yourself in the documentation for LoadLibrary, a zero return value means the function failed. Any other value means success. It doesn't say anything about being greater than or less than zero, so assume both: `if DllHandle <> 0 then TessDllLoaded := True;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you control the source DLL?  If not then no, the DLL relies on the C++ 2008 Runtime and it must be installed for the DLL to run and you need to add that as part of your install.

If you you do control the source for the DLL then statically link it to the C++ runtime, which will build the runtime into the DLL.

This issue has nothing to do with Windows XP.  The DLL requires the C++ 2008 runtime on Vista and 7 as well, it just so happens that the machines you tested with already had it installed.  The C++ runtime is not guaranteed to be installed on an any version of Windows.

Comment: +1: Compile it after having set the project option to statically link the C++ runtime.

Comment: Please don't give such advice. Statically linking against the runtime will be an issue if there are two DLL's relying on that runtime. You don't want to give both DLLs their own runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If the DLL needs the VS2008 redistributable then it needs it and you should include the redistributable as part of your product's installer.

Microsoft provide the redistributable packaged up for inclusion in other installers and it is intended to be used in this way. (It'll add a megabyte or two to your installer.)

There is no getting around this unless you have the source to the DLL and can recompile it to statically link the C Runtime.

(Even if you do have the source, simply recompiling with static linking may introduce bugs. It's possible the DLL assumes it shares the same heap as some other module(s) in the process and that's only the case if they all dynamically link to the same C Runtime DLL. Well designed DLLs avoid such assumptions but you'd need to double-check the way the DLL is written to be sure.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, my best guess would be that your TessDLL.DLL requires a DLL from the Visual C++ distributable.  If it can't find the given DLL, it fails to load.

If I am right on this, the only way it will work without it is if you have the source code to TessDLL.DLL and remove all dependencies on Visual C++'s DLL.

A good place to start debugging this is on a station where it actually works.  Make a little test program that load the DLL. Run it in the debugger and see what other DLL gets loaded when you load your DLL. If you're lucky, the probem *could* be in the version of an OS file that the MSVC redistributable happens to update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you ready for a stupid question? What if I include the .lib file with the dll?

Comment: " Run it in the debugger and see what other DLL gets loaded when you load your DLL" - Using Delphi 7, not sure exactly how to do that

Comment: Doesn't require a debugger, [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) does that. It's the first tool for DLL loading problems.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to installing Visual C++, I assume you have the DLL some place on your computer and installing VC puts another copy of the DLL possibly in your environment's PATH.

Have you tried putting the tessdll.dll in a location that is included in your search PATH?  Say System32 or in the same directory from which you're running your executable?  I'm not familiar with Delphi so I'm guessing at the logic of ExtractFilePath

Comment: Yes I have tried putting the dll in the windows\system32 folder, and installing the Visual C++ Runtime shouldn't "put another copy of the dll possible in your environment's PATH" unless I misunderstand something. You see, this DLL is compiled using a Visual C++ IDE, but installing the Visual C++ redistributable installs its own, separate stuff.

Answer (score 1):

"tessdll.dll". isn't that a DLL that's part of the [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29) OCR software? The Windows version is compiled with Visual C++ 6 and thus it needs those runtime libraries. Your version seems to be compiled with VC++ 2008.
If you have the RAD Studio version then you could download [the code](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr) and recompile it all with C++Builder, although that might need some adjustments. More information about the code also seems to be available [here](http://tesseract-ocr.repairfaq.org/main.html).

Comment: Alex Thanks for this. "The Windows version is compiled with Visual C++ 6 and thus it needs those runtime libraries." Any idea about what that practically means? Can I just put the 'runtime library' dlls in the same folder? If so which dlls? Do I have to register them? Do I have to run the installer (Runtime Library ReDistributable installer?) And why oh why would they not do a build of the DLL that doesn't require the runtime libraries. By the way this DLL is from version 2.04

Comment: There are tools which will display the DLL's that it will need. TDump.exe is part of Delphi, although there are alternatives. These could be used to check which DLL's it needs. Those could be placed in the same folder as the executable (and DLL) itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have this options:

1. Compile the DLL without requiring the runtime, but be aware of issues if you have multiple DLLs written with VC++2008 requiring a shared runtime
2. Install the VC++ 2008 redistributable, which will install a system-wide available runtime
3. Install the needed VC+2008 runtime DLLs in the same path as the DLL requiring it, thus having a "private" copy of that.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9(VS.90).aspx

Comment: "Install the needed VC+2008 runtime DLLs in the same path as the DLL requiring it, thus having a "private" copy of that" - by 'install' do you mean just deploy the file in the same directory as the other dll, or do you want me to use regsvr 32 to register it :p